# Validate numbers before and after decimal on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate decimal number of 13 digit before and 4 digit after decimal on key press, excluding comma, i.e comma shouldn't be counted as a digit.

**Valid Cases**

```
1,234,567,890,123.1234

1234567890123.1234

123456789012.1234

1234567890123.123

12345.123

1.2

0
```

**In Valid Cases**

```
12345abc.23 // string or special characters  not allowed

1,234,567,890,1231.1234

1,234,567,890,123.12341

12345678901231.1234

1234567890123.12341
```

**Current Regex**

```
^[0-9]{0,13}.?[0-9]{0,4}$
```

**Code**

```
 $("#Price").keydown(function (e) {

  var userVal =  $("#Price").val().replace(/,/g, ""); // remove commas

  var validValue = userVal.search(/^[0-9]{0,13}.?[0-9]{0,4}$/) == 0 ? true : false;

  if (userVal !== "" && !validValue && e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode !== 8) {        

     e.preventDefault();

  }
  else {

     return true;
  }

});
```

The above `regex` code works fine in browser console :

```
var userVal = "1234567890123.1234";

var validValue = userVal.search(/^[0-9]{0,13}.?[0-9]{0,4}$/) == 0 ? true : false;

console.log(validValue);
```

But using `keypress` , `keydown` and `keyup`  events, user is still able to type 1 extra digit before and after decimal.

How can I prevent user from typing the invalid cases ?

Comment: Just a side note: Some countries use different characters as decimal separator.

Comment: @Jan , Thanks, but can you tell what are those characters ?

Comment: In some countries they are flipped. For example in Germany it's: 1.000.000,00€

Comment: @stom [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) and [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) may help. So if you want to support localization, your code will need to adjust filters based on the locale. For example, a switch statement with locale ids as cases for the regex to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `keydown` is fired *before* the character is actually typed in the input. See this fiddle where I added outputs: https://jsfiddle.net/n56k0ve3/

```
<input id='price' type='text' value='0'></input>
<hr>
<span id='userVal'></span>
<br>
<span id='validValue'></span>


$("#price").keydown(function(e) {

  var userVal =  $(this).val().replace(/,/g, ""); // remove commas

  var validValue = userVal.search(/^[0-9]{0,13}\.?[0-9]{0,4}$/) == 0 ? true : false;

  $("#userVal").text(userVal);
  $("#validValue").text(validValue);

  if (userVal !== "" && !validValue && e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode !== 8) {
     e.preventDefault();
  } else {
     return true;
  }
});
```

Instead, use an event which checks the value after the value is changed. `keyup` works, but doesn't get fired until after the character is displayed in the input, and also fires unnecesilly, e.g., on <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Instead, we can use the `input` event. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2b6pc1hu/

```
var prevVal = $("#price").val();

$("#price").on('input', function(e) {

  var val = $(this).val();

  var userVal =  val.replace(/,/g, ""); // remove commas

  var validValue = userVal.search(/^[0-9]{0,13}\.?[0-9]{0,4}$/) == 0 ? true : false;

  $("#userVal").text(userVal);
  $("#validValue").text(validValue);

  if (userVal !== "" && !validValue && e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode !== 8) {
     $(this).val(prevVal);
  } else {
    prevVal = val;
  }
});
```

Also, in regular expressions `.` is a wildcard character. This should be escaped if you want it to only consume a period/decimal.

Comment: Brilliant answer, Actually I thought of getting the previous value and setting it but didn't try it. But this fixed the issue. Appreciate :)

Comment: I would suggest to use the "input" event, not the "keyup" event, since keyup detects any key (even if you press Shit or Ctrl or Alt the event will be triggered). "input" event only triggers when the element's value actually changed by a keyup.